# Post multiple requests to an API but without re-using connections

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a console application which is calling a third party API, basically it takes records from a database and pushes them to the third party via their WCF API.

For various reasons (Mainly the third party API being very slow - 7 seconds to respond) we want to post multiple records in parallel so we have started doing this, however we are now seeing some strange behaviour from the third party API where it is duplicating records.

It has been suggested to us by the developers of the API that this is because we are sending the requests over the same connection (which makes sense as .net will reuse connections) and they dont/cant/wont support that, they will only support one request over one connection and then the connection must be closed.

My question is, How do I do this in .net core (2.2) We are currently using a HttpClient which I'd expect to reuse connections where possible - how can I guarantee that we use a new connection for each request?

Comment: This is a perfect case of find another third party solution. The response you were given doesn't make sense and unsatisfactory to say the least. I mean what does the underlying socket connection have to do with simple concurrency / data integrity checks `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option, it's business critical (for us), we've been using it for years so it's quite integrated into the business, but now we need to use this api it's going to cause us issues. Moving to another product would cost us a significant amount.

Comment: Yeah i understand. However there are few things here that don't really make sense. The onus would be on the developers to fix the problem. In general you dont really have access to the socket layer on a WFC / HttpClient call, this is all done for you. Unless they are talking about higher level sessions then I cant ever see how this would ever be the problem. Can you show the actual minimal code to these calls ? are there tokens involved, is this actually WCF or are you using a HttpClient

Comment: Tried both using an http client and the vs2017 generated client, same result. Il get an example together in the morning, it's midnight here and I've had enough for the day! My understanding of the service is that it doesn't actually process the request it dumps the data in a queue, this is then processed by a windows service of some description which then returns a response to us.. how it does that is unclear, but that's apparently where the issue comes in. The api is EOL and technically out of support so we should be phasing it out eventually... But that doesn't help right now :)

Comment: I should probably also say that the developers of the third party API have not said that this is definitely the issue - just that its something we should investigate as its a "likely" cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have after some digging worked out what the problem is and there is no way to fix it.

The process is  :

1. We Post into the API
2. The API creates a record in a staging table in the database with a flag showing a status of "to be processed" and then starts polling the table waiting for change.
3. The API then invokes an executable on the server which looks at the staging table for any records with a status of "to be processed"
4. The executable does its processing and then changes the status on the record to "complete"
5. The API which has been polling the table sees the changed status, reads the record and returns the result to the client.

All fine if you only ever post one record at a time. But as Im executing in parallel what is happening is :

1. We call the API 10 times within a few ms of each other
2. The API creates 10 records in the staging table all with the "to be processed" status.
3. The API starts polling the staging table for changes and at the same time invokes the executable *TEN TIMES*
4. All 10 instances of the executable read all 10 records and process them - each instance unaware that there are another 9 instances all doing the same thing.
5. All 10 instances of the executable finish processing and change the status on the staging table to "complete"
6. The API sees the status change and returns all of the changed records to me in the response - So each of the 10 requests I sent gets 10 records returned to it.

Needless to say, we have entered into discussions with the provider of the API, it might be EOL and pretty much out of support but we're paying for licencing of this thing and this is a really stupid process that they need to provide a fix or a workaround for.

So in the end it was nothing to do with reusing connections, dont know why we were told it was.

Comment: So the issue is on API side where: _All 10 instances of the executable read all 10 records and process them_

Comment: What you can do to work around - create a queue on your side and send one message at the time (send next message only after receiving response for previous one)

Comment: Thats what we had at the time, the problem was that the API takes around 7 seconds to process a single request. We had more than one request coming through every 7 seconds so the queue just grew and grew to the point where it would never catch up.

The issue was entirely with the 3rd party API, we proved this multiple times. While we *still* wait for a fix from them we have limited the number of users on the system so that the queue can keep up processing one record at a time.